# Partition became RAW, TestDisk advice

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, partition-recovery, testdisk

~3 days ago a 238.2GB NTFS partition became RAW, losing ~170-180GB of data, and I have been trying to fix the problem for about 14 hours.

**Potential reasons partition went RAW:**

1. I have dual-booted Manjaro, although no idea why would this make my partition RAW.
2. When I use Linux, I always had to browse to the partition from file explorer before programs recognized it at `/run/media/peruna/Backup for Update`, and have never intentionally unmounted the drive.
3. I resized and moved the partition earlier in Linux KDE Partition Manager, but after ~1hr, it threw some error and aborted its job; I did the same procedure again and was able to complete the job.

**Symptoms found:**

- **Linux:** Dolphin file explorer doesn't show the drive
- **Windows:** Explorer shows the drive [`E:`], but no name or information, with the partition showing 0B of data and space

  - When trying to open the drive, I receive error:

    ```
    You need to format the disk in drive E: before you can use it. Do you want to format it?
    ```

    After canceling, I receive error:

    ```
    E:\ is not accessible. The volume does not contain a recognized file system. 
    Please make sure that all required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted.
    ```

---

**Everything tried so far:** *(Fast Startup disabled before dual-booting)*

- **iCare Data Recovery:** worked pretty good, but I also need the correct file structure and file names, since all the data on the partition is dependent on file names and structure
- **`TestDisk`:** I am not good at using this program and the tutorials don't seem to apply to my case, although I'm pretty sure `TestDisk` will be the program that will work in the end

  1. ```
     TestDisk 7.2-WIP, Data Recovery Utility, March 2021

     Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
     Current partition structure:

       Partition                     Start          End      Size in sectors
     1 P Windows Recovery Env         2048      1085439         1083392 [Basic data partition]
     2 P EFI System                1085440      1290239          204800 [EFI system partition]
         No FAT, NTFS, ext2, JFS, Reiser, cramfs or XFS marker
     3 P MS Reserved               1290240      1323007           32768 [Microsoft reserved partition]
     3 P MS Reserved               1290240      1323007           32768 [Microsoft reserved partition]
     4 P MS Data                   1323008   1249179569      1247856562 [Basic data partition]
         No FAT, NTFS, ext2, JFS, Reiser, cramfs or XFS marker
     5 P MS Data                1453981696   1953523711       499542016 [Basic data partition]
     5 P MS Data                1453981696   1953523711       499542016 [Basic data partition]
     6 P Linux filesys. data    1249179570   1451933695       202754126
     ```
  2. *Quick Search* does a quick jump to 74% in ~2s [`90300 / 121600 cylinders`], finding four partitions, receiving error two partitions can't be recovered *(partition needed not included)*:

     ```
     The harddisk (1000 GB / 931 GiB) seems too small! (< 1667 GB / 1552 GiB)
     Check the harddisk size: HD jumper settings, BIOS detection...

     The following partitions can't be recovered:

     Partition                       Start          End      Size in sectors
     Mac HFS                    1467399855   2308390576       840990722 [$_Func_impl@V<lambda_756265]
     Mac HFS                    1844913792   3255871105      1410957314
     ```
  3. General view of partitions, without the partition needed, but before *Quick Search* I saw a partition, as well as a duplicate of it, with a size of `499542016` sectors, which kind of matches the one I'm searching for:

     ```
     Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63

     Partition                       Start          End      Size in sectors
     P MS Data                        2048      1085439         1083392 [Recovery]
     P EFI System                  1085440      1290239          204800 [EFI System Partition] [NO NAME]
     D MS Data                     1323008   1249179569      1247856562
     D Mac HFS                   433956482   1844913795      1410957314
     D Mac HFS                   626409137   1467399858       840990722 [$_Func_impl@V<lambda_756265]
     D Linux filesys. data      1249179570   1451933689       202754120
     D Linux filesys. data      1662878752   1797094431       134215680
     ```

     - Fourth partition returned `HFS found using backup sector!`, with it and the fifth partitions returning upon opening:

       ```
       Support for this filesystem hasn't been implemented.
       ```
     - Seventh partition returns upon being opened:

       ```
       No file found, filesystem may be damaged.
       ```
  4. [Deep Search](https://pastebin.com/fXJ9Amcv) resulted in a lot of:

     ```
     file_pread(4,1,buffer,1953525169(121601/81/2)) lseek err Invalid argument
     ```

     This content preceeding them:

     ```
     Tue Mar 30 19:45:02 2021
     Command line: TestDisk

     TestDisk 7.2-WIP, Data Recovery Utility, March 2021

     OS: Windows 8 (9200)
     Compiler:   GCC 9.3, Cygwin 3001.4
     ext2fs lib: 1.45.3, ntfs lib: 10:0:0, reiserfs lib: none, ewf lib: 20140608, curses lib: ncurses 6.1

       disk_get_size_win32 IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO(/dev/sda)=1000204886016
       disk_get_size_win32 IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO(\\.\PhysicalDrive0)=1000204886016
       filewin32_getfilesize(\\.\PhysicalDrive1) GetFileSize err Incorrect function.

       filewin32_setfilepointer(\\.\PhysicalDrive1) SetFilePointer err Incorrect function.

       Warning: can't get size for \\.\PhysicalDrive1
         disk_get_size_win32 IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO(\\.\C:)=638902559744
         disk_get_size_win32 IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO(\\.\E:)=255765512192
         disk_get_size_win32 IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO(\\.\F:)=1507262464
         disk_get_size_win32 IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO(\\.\G:)=0
           Warning: can't get size for \\.\G:

     Hard disk list
       Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63, sector size=512 - TOSHIBA DT01ACA100, S/N:95J27VBNS, FW:MS2OA7L0
         Drive F: - 1507 MB / 1437 MiB - CHS 359 64 32, sector size=2048 - ASUS SH-224FB, FW:1.00

     Partition table type (auto): EFI GPT
       Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - TOSHIBA DT01ACA100
       Partition table type: EFI GPT

     Analyse Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
       hdr_size=92
       hdr_lba_self=1
       hdr_lba_alt=1953525167 (expected 1953525167)
       hdr_lba_start=34
       hdr_lba_end=1953525134
       hdr_lba_table=2
       hdr_entries=128
       hdr_entsz=128

       check_part_gpt failed for partition
         3 P MS Reserved              1290240    1323007        32768 [Microsoft reserved partition]
       check_part_gpt failed for partition
         5 P MS Data               1453981696  1953523711   499542016 [Basic data partition]

       Current partition structure:
         1 P Windows Recovery Env        2048     1085439     1083392 [Basic data partition]
         2 P EFI System               1085440     1290239      204800 [EFI system partition]
           No FAT, NTFS, ext2, JFS, Reiser, cramfs or XFS marker
         3 P MS Reserved              1290240     1323007       32768 [Microsoft reserved partition]
         3 P MS Reserved              1290240     1323007       32768 [Microsoft reserved partition]
         4 P MS Data                  1323008  1249179569  1247856562 [Basic data partition]
           No FAT, NTFS, ext2, JFS, Reiser, cramfs or XFS marker
         5 P MS Data               1453981696  1953523711   499542016 [Basic data partition]
         5 P MS Data               1453981696  1953523711   499542016 [Basic data partition]
         6 P Linux filesys. data   1249179570  1451933695   202754126

     search_part()
       Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
       NTFS at 0/32/33
         filesystem size           1083392
         sectors_per_cluster       8
         mft_lcn                   45141
         mftmirr_lcn               2
         clusters_per_mft_record   -10
         clusters_per_index_record 1
         NTFS part_offset=1048576, part_size=554696704, sector_size=512
         NTFS partition cannot be added (part_offset<part_size).
       NTFS at 0/32/33
         filesystem size           1083392
         sectors_per_cluster       8
         mft_lcn                   45141
         mftmirr_lcn               2
         clusters_per_mft_record   -10
         clusters_per_index_record 1
             MS Data                     2048    1085439    1083392 [Recovery]
             NTFS, blocksize=4096, 554 MB / 529 MiB

       FAT32 at 67/144/14
         FAT1 : 6654-7422
         FAT2 : 7423-8191
         start_rootdir : 8192 root cluster : 2
         Data : 8192-204799
         sectors : 204800
         cluster_size : 2
         no_of_cluster : 98304 (2 - 98305)
         fat_length 769 calculated 769
         set_FAT_info: name from BS used

     FAT32 at 67/144/14
       FAT: cluster=2(0x2), pos=1093632
           EFI System               1085440    1290239     204800 [EFI System Partition] [NO NAME]
           FAT32, blocksize=1024, 104 MB / 100 MiB

     NTFS at 82/90/9
       filesystem size           1247856562
       sectors_per_cluster       8
       mft_lcn                   49133508
       mftmirr_lcn               16
       clusters_per_mft_record   -10
       clusters_per_index_record 1
       NTFS part_offset=677380096, part_size=638902559744, sector_size=512
       NTFS partition cannot be added (part_offset<part_size).

     NTFS at 82/90/9
       filesystem size           1247856562
       sectors_per_cluster       8
       mft_lcn                   49133508
       mftmirr_lcn               16
       clusters_per_mft_record   -10
       clusters_per_index_record 1
           MS Data                  1323008 1249179569 1247856562
           NTFS, blocksize=4096, 638 GB / 595 GiB

     recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=0/773, s_mnt_count=28/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192
     recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
     recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 25344265
     recover_EXT2: part_size 202754120
     Filesystem created: Mon Mar 22 17:25:30 2021
     Last mount time:    Sat Mar 27 20:49:09 2021
         Linux filesys. data   1249179570 1451933689  202754120
         ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB, 103 GB / 96 GiB

     HFS magic value at 91341/106/13
       part_size 840990722
           Mac HFS               1467399855 2308390576  840990722 [$_Func_impl@V<lambda_756265]
           HFS blocksize=16777216, 430 GB / 401 GiB
       This partition ends after the disk limits. (start=1467399855, size=840990722, end=2308390576, disk end=1953525168)

     HFS magic value at 91341/106/15
       part_size 840990722
           Mac HFS                626409137 1467399858  840990722 [$_Func_impl@V<lambda_756265]
           HFS found using backup sector!, 430 GB / 401 GiB
             0 0000 0000 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
           Unknown               1575737412 5781186085 4205448674
           FATX, 2153 GB / 2005 GiB
             0 0000 0000 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
       Partition not added.

     recover_EXT2: s_block_group_nr=0/511, s_mnt_count=15/4294967295, s_blocks_per_group=32768, s_inodes_per_group=8192
     recover_EXT2: s_blocksize=4096
     recover_EXT2: s_blocks_count 16776960
     recover_EXT2: part_size 134215680
       Filesystem created: Mon Dec 23 14:02:17 2019
       Last mount time:    Wed Nov 18 17:29:59 2020
           Linux filesys. data   1662878752 1797094431  134215680
           ext4 blocksize=4096 Large_file Sparse_SB Recover, 68 GB / 63 GiB

     HFS magic value at 114840/145/58
       part_size 1410957314
           Mac HFS               1844913792 3255871105 1410957314
           HFS blocksize=16777216, 722 GB / 672 GiB
       This partition ends after the disk limits. (start=1844913792, size=1410957314, end=3255871105, disk end=1953525168)

     HFS magic value at 114840/145/60
       part_size 1410957314
           Mac HFS                433956482 1844913795 1410957314
           HFS found using backup sector!, 722 GB / 672 GiB
       file_pread(4,1,buffer,1953525168(121601/81/1)) ReadFile The drive cannot find the sector requested.
     ```

     It also returned a long list of partitions that do not fit in a PasteBin paste, so I've uploaded it to [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1huOxI3k1x0QwRK_2VlcmXdpKLedYokFT/view?usp=sharing):

     - At lines 44 and 53-54, I'm now sure these are the partitions I'm searching for, as while the size is about right and location exactly at the end of the disk, when I search the log, there is no partition with the size of `499542016` anywhere after the first 60 lines:

       ```
       Tue Mar 30 19:45:02 2021
       Command line: TestDisk

       TestDisk 7.2-WIP, Data Recovery Utility, March 2021

       OS: Windows 8 (9200)
       Compiler: GCC 9.3, Cygwin 3001.4
       ext2fs lib: 1.45.3, ntfs lib: 10:0:0, reiserfs lib: none, ewf lib: 20140608, curses lib: ncurses 6.1

         disk_get_size_win32 IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO(/dev/sda)=1000204886016
         disk_get_size_win32 IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO(\\.\PhysicalDrive0)=1000204886016
         filewin32_getfilesize(\\.\PhysicalDrive1) GetFileSize err Incorrect function.

         filewin32_setfilepointer(\\.\PhysicalDrive1) SetFilePointer err Incorrect function.

         Warning: can't get size for \\.\PhysicalDrive1
           disk_get_size_win32 IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO(\\.\C:)=638902559744
           disk_get_size_win32 IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO(\\.\E:)=255765512192
           disk_get_size_win32 IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO(\\.\F:)=1507262464
           disk_get_size_win32 IOCTL_DISK_GET_LENGTH_INFO(\\.\G:)=0
             Warning: can't get size for \\.\G:

         Hard disk list
           Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63, sector size=512 - TOSHIBA DT01ACA100, S/N:95J27VBNS, FW:MS2OA7L0
             Drive F: - 1507 MB / 1437 MiB - CHS 359 64 32, sector size=2048 - ASUS SH-224FB, FW:1.00

         Partition table type (auto): EFI GPT
           Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - TOSHIBA DT01ACA100
           Partition table type: EFI GPT

         Analyse Disk /dev/sda - 1000 GB / 931 GiB - CHS 121601 255 63
           hdr_size=92
           hdr_lba_self=1
           hdr_lba_alt=1953525167 (expected 1953525167)
           hdr_lba_start=34
           hdr_lba_end=1953525134
           hdr_lba_table=2
           hdr_entries=128
           hdr_entsz=128

           check_part_gpt failed for partition
             3 P MS Reserved              1290240    1323007      32768 [Microsoft reserved partition]
           check_part_gpt failed for partition
             5 P MS Data               1453981696 1953523711  499542016 [Basic data partition]
           Current partition structure:
             1 P Windows Recovery Env        2048    1085439    1083392 [Basic data partition]
             2 P EFI System               1085440    1290239     204800 [EFI system partition]
               No FAT, NTFS, ext2, JFS, Reiser, cramfs or XFS marker
             3 P MS Reserved              1290240    1323007      32768 [Microsoft reserved partition]
             3 P MS Reserved              1290240    1323007      32768 [Microsoft reserved partition]
             4 P MS Data                  1323008 1249179569 1247856562 [Basic data partition]
               No FAT, NTFS, ext2, JFS, Reiser, cramfs or XFS marker
             5 P MS Data               1453981696 1953523711  499542016 [Basic data partition]
             5 P MS Data               1453981696 1953523711  499542016 [Basic data partition]
             6 P Linux filesys. data   1249179570 1451933695  202754126

         search_part()
       ```
  5. I found a few partitions (Mac HFS) with a size of 268 GB / 250 GiB in the *Deeper Scan*, so these might be what I'm searching for; however, there are many of them and I can't view the files because `Support for this filesystem hasn't been implemented.`

     ```
     HFS found using backup sector!, 268GB / 250GiB"
     ```

     I found this at lines 43-44, which is the partition I'm searching for:

     ```
     check_part_gpt failed for partition 5 P MS Data 1453981696 1953523711 499542016 [Basic data partition]
     ```

     Does this error message mean something big?

How should I proceed?

Comment: Submitting commentary doesn’t “bump” your question.  Additionally, commentary that attempts to do that will simply be deleted as not being necessary so it’s counter productive.  If there is anything of value in any of the commentary you should edit your question

Comment: When crafting longer questions/answers, correct markdown, and markdown in general, becomes extremely vital to break up the content into its relevant sections, else the readability of the content becomes vastly more difficult to parse _(I'm generally partial to an outline format since its often the most efficient method to get a lot of information across sanely)_. Monospaced code markdown should be used for monospaced code, either backticks for a short amount of monospaced code or code fences for a code box, Normally, I'd simply edit the content, but editing this question would take 30+ minutes

Comment: Have you already posted your question at the Testdisk forum?

Comment: Nope, is there one? @r2d3

Comment: https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/

Comment: I got so tired of trying to recover the data that I just decided to format the partition and download everything again (I lost 12 programs / 170 GB of data) in ~47 hours + ~9 hours of extracting and installing stuff.